# 3 Algorithms in the same column with algorithmic

Tags: floats, algorithms

I have 3 algorithms that I want to be displayed in the same column of a 2-column document.  They are all slight variations of each  other, so it is important that they be displayed right next to each other for easy comparison.

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to place all three in the column.  I've tried putting them inside a figure environment, but then I get the error "Not in outer par mode."  Using another algorithm package is not an option for me.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is using floats in a `twocolumn` document. Although it is possible, your needs do not conform to their purpose. Instead, the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) removes the float-y-ness of floats, allowing you to specify a caption in the text where it is called.

The following [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) uses [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `algpseudocode` to display an algorithm with slight variations across the three. The main interface for non-floating captions using `caption` is

```
\captionof{<float env>}{<caption>}
```

Since I loaded [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), `<float env>` can be `algorithm` to obtain the appropriate caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\begin{document}
\lipsum[87]
\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm A}\label{euclidA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{GCD of $a$ and $b$}
    \State $r_1\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{$r=0\mapsto\mbox{answer}$}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile1}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The GCD is $b$}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm B}\label{euclidB}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{GCD of $a$ and $b$}
    \State $r_2\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{$r=0\mapsto\mbox{answer}$}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile2}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The GCD is $b$}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm C}\label{euclidC}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{GCD of $a$ and $b$}
    \State $r_3\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{$r=0\mapsto\mbox{answer}$}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile3}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The GCD is $b$}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) were just used for layout and dummy text.

There's also the stand-alone [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) which does something similar, as well as [`ccaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ccaption).

---

Keeping things together in a float-like environment is possible. Wrap the set of algorithms in a `figure` (yes, a `figure`, or `table`) environment while still using `\captionof{algorithm}`, or just place them all in an `algorithm` environment with a `\caption` for each. The following shows the former:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[t]
\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm A}\label{euclidA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{GCD of $a$ and $b$}
    \State $r_1\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{$r=0\mapsto\mbox{answer}$}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile1}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The GCD is $b$}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm B}\label{euclidB}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{GCD of $a$ and $b$}
    \State $r_2\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{$r=0\mapsto\mbox{answer}$}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile2}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The GCD is $b$}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\captionof{algorithm}{Euclid’s algorithm C}\label{euclidC}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{GCD of $a$ and $b$}
    \State $r_3\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{$r=0\mapsto\mbox{answer}$}
    \State $a\gets b$
    \State $b\gets r$
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile3}
  \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The GCD is $b$}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

You may have to adjust the space between the `algorithmic` and `\captionof` to suit your needs.

Comment: This does not solve my problem.  If you change the first `\lipsum[87]` into `\lipsum[1-2]`, then the algorithms get broken up into multiple columns.  I don't care if it automatically floats it away from the position of the text, I just want all three algorithms to be one after the other in the same column.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki wrap the three algorithms (in Werner's code, from right after `\lipsum[87]` up to the third `\end{algorithmic}`) inside a floating environment; `figure`, for example.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That was what I tried originally, but I get the "Not in outer par mode" error.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki this is because you are using `\caption`; notice that Werner's example uses `\captionof` from the `caption` package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's not the `\caption` that was breaking it, but the `algorithm` environment that I was putting it into that Werner's example didn't put it into (I get the same error even without a caption).  Is there any way I can still get that environment's aesthetics with only using `\captionof`?

Comment: @MikeIzbicki But if you use *just one* `algorithm` environment for all three algorithms, there's no need to do anything more; `algorithm` is a floating object, so the three algorithms won't be split. Simply wrap all three `algorithmic` environments inside one single `algorithm` environment; you still can give a standard `\caption` command for each one of the algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can convert an algorithm into a non-float by appending an [H] at the end of it.  This code works for what I wanted to do:

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Alg 1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Alg 1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Alg 1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{figure}
```